# Как получить скомпилированный .tex файл

Tags: latex, tex

Есть TeXStudio
Есть код:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{D:/res/image.png}
\end{document}
```

При компиляции программа мне выдает готовый PDF, но он мне не нужен
Мне нужен именно: **уже скомпилированный tex файл**

Объясню подробнее:
Я редактирую файлы одной игры, там есть текструра - картинка с расширением .webp
Рядом с ней лежит скомпилированный texture.tex, в нем как я понимаю прописан путь до этой картинки или она просто в нем как-то объявлена.
Текст в texture.tex который показывает любой редактор естественно виден как кракозябры и еще что-то непонятное.

**Моя задача: создать аналог этого файла, прописав туда путь до своей текстуры со своим именем и скомпилировать**

TeXStudio скачал только сегодня, про tex узнал только сегодня.

Comment: ваш файл с именем `texture.tex` явно не имеет никакого отношения к [программе *tex*, написанной Дональдом Кнутом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX). если упомянутая вами программа *texstudio* имеет какое-то отношение именно к программе *tex*, то и она тоже к вашему файлу никак не применима. // исходные файлы для программы *tex*, при именовании которых часто используют суффикс `.tex` — это самые обыкновенные текстовые файлы, пример их содержимого вы, кстати, и привели в начале вопроса..

Comment: ну  а при компилировании этот исходник tex файла разве нигде не сохраняется в скомпилированном виде?

Comment: сохраняется, конечно. и pdf можно получить, и dvi, и ps, и html в конце концов. не говоря уж про всякие epub, mobi, fb2 и всякое такое прочее. но всё это не имеет **никакого** отношения ни каким «текстурам». вы «не в ту сторону смотрите».

Comment: Спасибо, погуглил и вроде да - не туда смотрю, а можете подсказать куда смотреть?